# How is the postgres actually getting some of the columns? Execution plan question

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, cte

I've got a table with a bunch of columns. Among them `facility_id` and `po_date`. I'm writing a complex query and I have an index on those two columns. You can see from the planner output below that Postgres is using that index as the index condition when it's joining to my `facility` table.

My question is actually in regards to the presence of columns enumerated in the `Filter:` line below. `exclude`, `verified`, and `deleted` are not in the index referenced at the top and so how is Postgres actually getting at the data in those columns? I would've expected a full table scan to be explicitly cited however there isn't one in sight anywhere. Can a full table scan be quietly hidden in a `Filter`?

This table is 50M rows in size, and I'm on Postgres 10. Also, this portion of the query is in a CTE.

```
->  Index Scan using clustered_table_facility_id_po_date_idx on clustered_table cp  (cost=0.56..1401.08 rows=31929 width=37) (actual time=0.021..5.331 rows=9572 loops=3640)
      Index Cond: (facility_id = af.id)
      Filter: ((NOT exclude) AND (verified IS NULL) AND (deleted IS NULL))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 2819
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect a full table scan when you have a usable index?

The optimizer gathers all conditions, considers available indexes (and other ways) and picks a "best" plan. In your case that plan is:

1. from previous step get `af.id`
2. using the index identify all rows
   that have `(facility_id = af.id)` - that's possible because an index is not a standalone structure, it is based on its table and each item in the index contains a pointer to an actual row of the table
3. fetch those identified rows and check the rest of the conditions (the `Filter` part)
4. return the rows that matched to the outer plan node for remaining work

`Index Scan` means that the index is used to locate relevant rows, but it does not mean that the table would not be touched, only that it would not be scanned fully.

There is a possibility for an `Index Only Scan` - when the index contains all the relevant column (not only those in ON/WHERE, but selected ones and ones used to order, all columns the query needs from the table). In such case actually fetching the full row from the table may not be required - but some rows are fetched anyway, because the *transaction visibility* is not available on the index level for all rows, only for entire blocks (a bit complex issue).